# In extjs4.1,how to design progressbar which gets increamented as per serverside value provided

Tags: progress-bar, extjs4.1

i am working in extjs 4.1. I want to show progressbar. This progressbar should get increament with value provided by server and also want to display this percentage along with progressbar. Suppose percentage value retrived from server is 33%,then progressbar should get increamented upto 33%. If value becomes 50% , then progressbar also get increamented upto 50%.I just know about including progressbar as=

```
{
   xtype : 'progressbar',
    width : 300
}
```

So how to implement my scenario in extjs4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to get a reference to your progress bar in your code where you receive your server side data and then use the updateProgress and updateText methods. Read more on these at the links below

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar-method-updateProgress

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar-method-updateText

Comment: I have written code as:                                                                                progressbar = updateFormStatusWindow.queryById('progressbar');
progressbar.updateProgress(jsonData.percentage.toFixed(2), jsonData.percentage.toFixed(2))....But progress bar is getting increamented upto 100% before server response reaches to 100%. Server is sending 45%,and then too progressbar completes 100%. So how to overcome it.

Comment: What does jsonData.percentage.toFixed(2) read as if you debug when the  data comes back from server?

Comment: Solved issue by doing = progressbar.updateProgress(jsonData.percentage.toFixed(2)/100, jsonData.percentage.toFixed(2))